# duplicate search field appearing with just one block

Tags: search

There's suddenly two search fields appearing on my dev site. I'm afraid I'm not sure what the last change was before this.

There's just one standard Drupal search block configured

[image: screenshot]

here's the html from chrome's inspector

```
<div id="block-search-form" class="block block-search contextual-links-region last even" role="search">

      <div class="contextual-links-wrapper"><ul class="contextual-links"><li class="block-configure first last"><a href="/admin/structure/block/manage/search/form/configure?destination=node">Configure block</a></li>
</ul></div>
  <form action="/" method="post" id="search-block-form" accept-charset="UTF-8"><div><div class="container-inline">
      <h2 class="element-invisible">Search form</h2>
    <div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-search-block-form">
  <label class="element-invisible" for="edit-search-block-form--2">Search </label>
 <input title="Enter the terms you wish to search for." type="text" id="edit-search-block-form--2" name="search_block_form" value="" size="15" maxlength="128" class="form-text">
</div>
<div class="form-actions form-wrapper" id="edit-actions"><input type="submit" id="edit-submit--6" name="op" value="Search" class="form-submit"></div><input type="hidden" name="form_build_id" value="form-siNBZmrvpwkL6N9gfwu4Li2LBMPzp0TVxw81H7C4H2U">
<input type="hidden" name="form_token" value="nxWBZ6gSMs4INvrbfpGyfd4DTr2QhLdfSrjuYA5PSC0">
<input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="search_block_form">
</div>
</div></form>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache already?

Comment: Yes, that's not it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably a css problem.

My guess is the search bar is using a background image. The image contains both the inactive search background and the active search background. It's a good thing to avoid to load 2 different images.
If you want this to work, you need to ensure that the search box has a fixed height.

So in the css, you should have something like :

```
#edit-search-block-form--2 {
  height: 10px;   /* 10px => replace this with the real height */
}
```